# Использование классов для инкапсуляции dll

Tags: классы, c++

***Снова не могу - не ответить, не прокомментировать!***

Есть API стороннего производителя в в виде dll написанная на C. Содержит в себе как обычные функции так и функции обратного вызова (API осуществляет взаимодействие с некоторым приложением). Раз я использую C++ логичней было бы завернуть всё это дело в класс, для дальнейшего использования в моём проекте,  планирую использовать отдельные .cpp и .h, для данного класса!

Как я понял использовать CallBack Функции внутри класса не получится из за необходимости использовать Extern "C". Придётся вовремя вызова CallBack, из тела CallBack вызывать соответствующую статическую функцию класса, как то кривовато!?

С одной стороны инициализация API, производится один раз, CallBack функции представлены единичным экземпляром, с другой для получения и обработки данных уместно использовать несколько экземпляров класса. Как то надо всё это соединить в одно целое! Интерфейс к моему классу должен быть минимален, понятен для использования сторонними разработчиками. В общем хотелось бы получит следующее:

```
  main(){

  myClass ProcessData_1, ProcessData_2, ... ,
  myClass::InitConnection(...);
  long StatusConnection=myClass::StatusConnection();
  ProcessData_1.Set(...);
  long A=ProcessData_1.Get();

  }
```

Comment: Собственно, уже комментировал:

>У меня есть несколько вариантов в таком случае:
 1. Если какой-то параметр/результат, передаваемый/получаемый в SET_CALLBACK (pnExtendedErrorCode или lpstrErrorMessage) можно извлечь из CallBack'а (и он уникален), то можно сопоставить объект с ним. А в колбеке производить поиск по списку таких сопоставлений, чтобы найти нужный экземпляр класса.
 2. Если параметры, передаваемые в SET_CALLBACK можно извлечь еще и по адресу и адрес такого какого-то параметра не меняется в API, то можно "прицепить" объект к такому параметру, это будет работать быстрее.

Comment: То, что возвращается через CallBack никак не связано с параметрами функции настраивающей вызов CallBack!

Comment: Легко - http://www.quik.ru/depot/Trans2QuikAPI_1.1.rar

Comment: >@mega у вас есть ICQ ?

@rejie, давайте, как-нибудь в другой раз, у меня работы на самом деле хватает.

Answer (score 3):

Для чего-то более вразумительного нужно больше информации по самому `API`. А то, что Вы описали кодом, подразумевает "выделение класса" `Connection`.

> Легко - http://www.quik.ru/depot/Trans2QuikAPI_1.1.rar

Посмотрел. Да, действительно, здесь нет возможности сопоставить объект с вызовом `API` (для примера смотрел на сигнатуры `TRANS2QUIK_SET_CONNECTION_STATUS_CALLBACK` и `TRANS2QUIK_SET_TRANSACTIONS_REPLY_CALLBACK`). Но, подозреваю, здесь нет и поддержки "множественных `Callback'ов`".

Т.е., к примеру: вызов `TRANS2QUIK_SET_CONNECTION_STATUS_CALLBACK` с колбеком `b` перезапишет колбек `a`, выставленный этой функцией ранее.

Т.е., можете спокойно реализовывать эти функции **статично**. Функционал библиотеки просто не поддерживает такую динамику, какую Вы хотите.

p.s.: здесь одной только длиной названий функций можно закопать трех программистов :)

**Комментарии:**

> Понял, вы предлагаете сопоставить 1 экземпляр класса - 1 CallBack функции, у нас 4 CallBack, то есть создаём 4 экземпляра класса?

[[@rejie](/users/263/rejie)](/users/263/rejie), я предлагаю сопоставить с колбеками не экземпляр класса, а статический **указатель** на экземпляр класса ( в примере - это `cb_obj` ). Т.е., на 4 типа колбеков будет 4 статических указателя.

Соответственно, в классе для каждого типа колбека будет 4 метода, которые будут регистрировать объект за данным колбеком. Регистрация - это установка в соответствующий статический указатель значения `this`. А все 4 вызова `TRANS2QUIK_SET_..._CALLBACK` и т.п. можно сделать при инициализации библиотеки, один раз.

Поскольку реализация библиотеки однопоточная, или одноканальная, то такая работа с объектами должна быть удобна.

> Таким образом в экземпляре Вашего класса нужен только один указатель на `Callback`.

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp), а вот с этого момента уже я Вас не понял. :) Если сам `Callback` заполняет приходящий массив, зачем в классе на него указатель?

> API скидывает через CallBack общую таблицу, со всеми операциями, Акциями и т.п.(1,2,3-CallBack функции - 3 таблицы с различными параметрами)

Начинаю понимать. Т.е. Вы выступаете в роли "пассивного наблюдателя". Я до этого момента полагал, что `SetCallback` инициирует какой-то обмен данными, а у Вас получается, что инициатор обмена - сам сервер, и Вы можете только к нему подключиться, чтобы послушать, что он вещает.

В таком случае, предлагаю такую схему: заводим 2 класса: `Watcher` и `Delegate`.

`Watcher` - это класс, который будет собирать у себя таблицы, приходящие с сервера.

`Delegate` - делегат ценной бумаги, который работает с `Watcher`'ом, принимая от него всю информацию по конкретной бумаге.

`Watcher` будет работать, как я описавал раньше, т.е. будет регистрировать себя для соответствующих `CallBack'ов`. В таком случае, `Watcher` должен быть один. Но, если потребуется другая логика обработки таблиц, вполне возможно переключение `Delegate'ов` между несколькими `Watcher'ами`. Таким образом, концепции `ООП` будут уместны в Вашей работе.

За соединением с сервером предлагаю следить либо `Watcher'ам`, либо завести для этого аналогичный ( аналогичный по работе с `CallBack'ами` ) класс, типа `SrvStatus`.

> Но ведь это оправданный подход для C++ ?

Запрещать создание нескольких экземпляров класса? По-моему - нет, не оправдано. Не думаю, что в этой задаче требуется такое поведение. Вы и так через статический указатель контролируете, что `CallBack` будет взаимодействовать с делегатом **только через один объект** слежения.

А в методе `Connect` я имел ввиду просто установку статического указателя в значение `this`. Т.е. любой `Connect` подсоединит текущий и автоматически отсоединит любой другой `Watcher` от `API`. Т.е. `Connect` - в смысле **подключиться к `API`**, а не к серверу.

Соответственно, можно написать аналогичные `Connected` и `Disconnect`, если потребуется. Это будет красиво, гибко и понятно.

> Меня смущает, что если вводить отдельный класс `Connect` который будет отвечать за инициализацию и связь нужен в одном экземпляре!

В смысле класс `Connection`? А почему смущает? Все логично: `Connection` следит за состоянием связи с сервером. Вы можете создать несколько экземпляров `Connection`, но следить за сервером будет только один, как и в случае с `Watcher'ом`, например: один потомок `Connection'а` о состоянии сервера сообщает через диалоговые сообщения, другой может писать лог, третий - слать диагностику + `timestamp` на сервер и т.п.

Если в какой-то программе, которая будет использовать Вашу обертку над `API`, реализуется триггер на использование того или иного типа диагностики состояния сервера (или различные "представления" [`views`] `Watcher'ов`), то множественные экземпляры `CallBack-классов` и их `Connect'ы` сразу найдут себе применение.

> Блин, меня бесит, не могу соединить не соединяемоё!

Из того, что мне известно, вроде все должно быть понятно.
Давайте разберем по шагам.

1. Выделяем базовый `CallBack`-класс:

   ```
   struct CallBack{
     static CallBack*pActive = NULL;
     static void __stdcall CB( long nTransactionResult, ... ){
       if( pActive ){
         pActive->OnReceive( nTransactionResult, ... );
       }
     }
     static void Initialize( ... ){
       TRANS2QUIK_SET_CONNECTION_STATUS_CALLBACK( CallBack::CB, ... );
     }
     void Connect( void ){
       pActive = this;
     }
     virtual void OnReceive( ... ) = 0;
   };
   ```
2. Выделяем класс `Watcher`:

   ```
   struct Watcher : public CallBack{
     std::vector< Column >  Columns;
     std::function< void( CallBack* ) >OnUpdate;
     virtual void OnReceive( ... ){
       //  ... какая-то реализация заполнения таблицы Columns ... 
       OnUpdate( this );
     }
     void Select( ... ){
       //  ... какая-то реализация выборки из таблицы Columns ...
     }
   };
   ```
3. Выделяем класс `Delegate`:

   ```
   struct Delegate{
     Watcher*pWatcher;
     long SomeTradeID;
     void SelectTrade( ... ){
       SomeTradeID = ...;
     }
     void Connect( Watcher*_pWatcher ){
       pWatcher = _pWatcher;
     }
     void Select( ... ){
       if( pWatcher ){
         pWatcher->Select( ... SomeTradeID ... );
       }
     }
   };
   ```
4. Пишем пример программы:

   ```
   int main( int argc, char**argv ){
     Watcher MyWatcher;
     Delegate D1, D2;
     //  связываем делегаты с Watcher'ом
     D1.Connect( &MyWatcher );
     D2.Connect( &MyWatcher );
     //  настраиваем делегаты на какие-то конкретные бумаги
     D1.SelectTrade( /*Выбираем какую-то одну ценную бумагу*/ );
     D2.SelectTrade( /*Выбираем какую-то другую ценную бумагу*/ );
     //  настраиваем событие обновления Watcher'а
     MyWatcher.OnUpdate = [ & ]( CallBack*pW ){
       if( pW == &MyWatcher ){
         // обновляем текущее состояние бумаг
         D1.Select( ... );
         D2.Select( ... );
         // печатаем в консоль результаты по D1 и D2
         printf( ... D1 ..., D2 ... );
       }
     };
     //  связываем MyWatcher с API
     MyWatcher.Connect();
     //  инициируем `Callback`
     CallBack::Initialize( ... );
     //  ждем реакции от сервера и слаженной работы всей цепочки объектов
     _getch();
     return 0;
   }
   ```

Только для примера у меня все классы - структуры.
Как-то так я представляю ваши торги :)

Comment: Так и получается, что будет вызван CallBack(в единственном экземпляре) вне класса, в его теле придётся прописать вызов статического метода из моего класса с транслированием полученных данных!?

Comment: Нет, Вы так же можете реализовать свой метод внутри класса, просто сделайте глобальную ссылку на объект, который ставит колбек:

 class MyClass{
   static MyClass*cb_obj = NULL;
 }

 void MyClass::SetStatusCB( ... ){
   cb_obj = this;
   TRANS2QUIK_SET_CONNECTION_STATUS_CALLBACK( CallBack, ... );
 }
а в самом колбеке - вызов обработчика:

 ... CallBack( ... ){
   MyClass::cb_obj->DoCB( ... );
 }

Comment: А для чего прибегать к указателям? Возможно же так?

    class MyClass{
      static ProcCallBack(...){...};
    }

    ... CallBack(a, b, c){
      MyClass:: ProcCallBack(a, b, c);
     }

Comment: >А для чего прибегать к указателям?

Чтобы статический колбек знал, какому экземпляру класса передать управление.

>Возможно же так?

В таком случае `ProcCallBack` сможет использовать только статичные функции класса, т.е. к объектам она не будет иметь ни какого отношения. Вы же хотели поддержку ООП?

Comment: @mega извиняюсь за карикатуру, но графически мои мысли можно изобразить так:   http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20121204/E3VNnXlZ.jpg
:)

Comment: >графически мои мысли можно изобразить так: http://s1.ipicture.ru/uploads/20121204/E3VNnXlZ.jpg

Я конечно не знаю всех тонкостей Вашей реализации, но из того, что понял: получается, что в контейнере накапливаются данные с запросов всех экземпляров класса? После чего каждый экземпляр делает выборку того, что он конкретно запрашивал? Не выгоднее ли хранить полученные данные непосредственно в экземплярах, не сбрасывая все в кучу? Ведь `Callback` в моей реализации точно знает, какому экземпляру принадлежат данные.

Comment: Понял, вы предлагаете сопоставить 1 экземпляр класса - 1 CallBack функции, у нас 4 CallBack, то есть создаём 4 экземпляра класса?

Comment: @rejie, а может посмотреть на это проще?

Насколько я понял, каждый экземпляр Вашего класса это отдельное соединение. Ответы получает некий Callback. Почему бы в Вашем классе не иметь просто 2 контейнера, один отправляемые/отправленные данные (не знаю что там на самом деле должно быть), а другой полученные данные (заполняется   Саllbak-ом, точнее его "оберткой"). 

Таким образом в экземпляре Вашего класса нужен только один указатель на Callback. Конкретный адрес задается при инициализации соединения.

Comment: отредактировал ответ

Comment: @mega,

    @avp, а вот с этого момента уже я Вас не понял. :) Если сам Callback заполняет приходящий массив, зачем в классе на него указатель?

я имел в виду, что это функция, которая запоминается при инициализации экземпляра (кстати, это в свете дальнейших объяснений @rejie похоже стало не актуально, но предполагалось, что ее в принципе можно менять), а потом при работе с внешним API ее адрес передается туда (это же и есть Callback? Я правильно понимаю?). 

Насколько я понимаю этому API нужна функция пользователя (на Си, а не С++), которую он вызывает в определенных условиях. Так?

Answer (score 3):

Опять не могу комментировать...

[[[[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega) при помощи метода SetStatusCB мы устанавливаем какой именно экземпляр класса будет обрабатывать CallBack`и ?

[[@avp](/users/232/avp)](/users/232/avp) [[[[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega) Каждый экземпляр класса хранит конкретные параметры, например Название Акции (ценная бумага торгуемая на бирже) по которой будут произведена операция (метод купить или продать), в этом же экземпляре будут храниться информация пришедшая с биржи через CallBack - проведена операция успешно или нет, и т.п.

Каждый экземпляр класса будет сопровождать операции по конкретной Акции. API скидывает через CallBack общую таблицу, со всеми операциями, Акциями и т.п.(1,2,3-CallBack функции - 3 таблицы с различными параметрами)  Задача экземпляров класса выбрать из этих таблиц своё и обработать!

Помимо этого 4-Callback отвечает за соединение с сервером, то есть отношения к отдельным экземплярам не имеет, поэтому его обрабатывать нужно вне экземпляров класса!

Возможно так будет ясней! И вообще, не судите я только учусь! :)

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

>@mega при помощи метода `SetStatusCB` мы устанавливаем какой именно экземпляр класса будет обрабатывать CallBack`и ?

Да, так.

Comment: @mega вы всё правильно поняли, получается, что нам нужен один экземпляр класса Watcher, в конструкторе которого делаем проверку на создание единичного экземпляра, инициализируем cb_obj = this, TRANS2QUIK_SET_:1,2,3,4 и создаем 4 функции обработчика CallBack DoCB_1, DoCB_2, DoCB_3, DoCB_4 которые вызываем из соответствующих CallBack`ов через статический указатель ?

Comment: Проверку в конструкторе не надо. По мне, так это противоречит принципам `ООП`. А вот в самом `CallBack'е` - да, пожалуй надо проверить, создан ли в системе хоть один `Watcher`. И `TRANS2QUIK_SET_` стоит вызвать только один раз, при инициализации всей программы/библиотеки/модуля, т.к. `CallBack` - один, какой смысл его им же переназначать? А остальное - да, именно так я предполагаю работу с этой `API`.

Comment: Кстати, если регистрировать `Watcher` только в конструкторе, то получается, невозможно будет переключаться между `Watcher'ами` в `Run-Time'е`. По моему, для этого тут просится метод `Connect`. Не находите?

Comment: Нда... замысловато получается с этим ООП!
Но ведь это оправданный подход для C++ ?


Если глобально мыслить, то да нужен и Connect, тем более кроме инициализации обратного вызова, необходим метод подключения(отключения) DLL к терминалальному приложению QUIK которое в свою очередь уже и подключается к Серверу QUIK (функция вложена в API) а без этого подключения никакие Callback`и вызываться не будут!

Вот и думаю как это всё красиво завернуть и как назвать классы!

Comment: Блин, меня бесит, не могу соединить не соединяемоё! :( Хоть скажите это правильная идея, эту dll завернуть в класс для дальнейшего использования уже на более высоком уровне!? Или тоже не плохой вариант оформить в виде функций и там где уже сам доктор прописал использовать классы, все это разместить в одном файле, написать интерфейсный хидер, и хидер для реализации не интерфейсных функций и класов, затем к основному проекту подключить хидер интерфейса и вуаля!

Comment: @rejie, а реально, зачем Вам ООП? Подумайте о задаче, как о преобразовании потока данных.

--

Как я понял, задача - смотреть некие данные (акции). Для этого есть библиотека, которая предлагает установить callback на Си. Видимо этот callback должен их (получаемые данные) куда-то складывать (наверное в очередь, конкретнее в список).

Вот пусть просто добавляет. Другие потоки могут их оттуда забирать и что-то с ними делать. Собственно вырисовывается одна структура данных, может быть защищенная мьютексом для многопоточного использования.

Или я чего-то принципиального на понимаю?

Comment: Принципиальности возможно и нет, хочу выполнить поставленную задачу так как если бы её решал хороший программист со стажем (C++) Виде отдельных функций я уже реализовал, не хватает какой то систематизации, проект может стать большим, будут и другие модули и на мой взгляд код должен быть максимально понятен и эффективен!

Comment: @rejie, не думаю, что код большого проекта (независимо от языка) может быть хоть как-то понятен и эффективен без предварительного проектирования независимо от языка.

Такое впечатление, что Вы хотите кинуться к клавиатуре не имея четкого плана, форматов всех данных и протоколов обмена ими между модулями Вашей системы. (Это если речь о *большом* проекте).

Если же это прототип, то он будет десять раз переделываться и не стоит сейчас думать об универсальности классов. Нормальные классы получаются сами собой, когда *на практике* некие куски кода оказываются востребованными в нескольких модулях.

Comment: @rejie "Хороший программист со стажем (C++)"... Поищите высказывания Степанова (автор STL -- надеюсь для Вас достаточно авторитетная личность) об ООП.

@avp Рассуждения в целом разумные, но. От языка зачастую зависит очень много -- Вы без проблем представите решение на одном языке и замучаетесь с реализацией на другом, если объём текста будет на порядок больше. Насчёт прототипов: была история про проект фирмы Sendmail Inc. на erlang'е (см. google). Они делали на erlang'е прототип, чтобы потом написать (на C++), но когда посмотрели, как прототип работает, на переписывание забили.

Comment: @rejie, отредактировал ответ!

Comment: @alexlz,

    От языка зачастую зависит очень много

Естественно. Просто, говоря о проектировании независимо от языка я, видимо, не очень удачно выразил мысль, что сначала делается проект (верхнего уровня) на уровне модулей, основных структур данных и протоколов, а потом выбирается язык (или несколько языков) для их реализации.

Затем, само-собой уже с учетом языка, проводим детальное проектирование модуля - программирование - перепроектирование - программирование - тестирование и т.д.

И параллельно с первым перепроектированием начинаем ваять документацию (в т.ч. сразу для тестирования).

Comment: @avp возможно так хотят представить проектирование. Но вот модули в отрыве от языка -- это что-то интересное (например дать задание реализовать один и тот же модуль на C++ и прологе).

Comment: @alexlz, под модулем я понимаю часть системы, которая достаточно самостоятельна (выполняет осмысленный набор функций) и связана с другими модулями по данным (возможно и по библиотекам, но это определяется не в начале проектирования). Некоторые модули могут запускать другие. 

Понятно, что эти функции часто предопределяют язык реализации. С другой стороны, участники команды накладывают ограничения на набор языков (а часто и на круг реализуемых систем).

Сказанное относится к проектам от 100000 строк.

--

А зачем выдавать дурацкие задания?

Comment: @avp не по теме, просто вспомнилась статья про винегрет из языков: http://www.pcweek.ru/idea/article/detail.php?ID=82311